# How to divide by variable that belongs to y in Sympy

Tags: sympy

I am making an separable differential equation solver. In order to make an expression that separated by x and y variables I have to divide expression on the right by every variable that belong to s such as `sin(y), e**y, y**2, ...`
I am using Sympy

```
def equationseparator(diffeq):
    x, y, z, e= sym.symbols("x y z e")

    separateddiff, separatedeq = diffeq.split("=")
    variables_of_eq = re.split('[(|)]', separatedeq)
    eq = sym.parse_expr(separatedeq)
    variables_of_eq_ordered = []
    variables_of_eq_ord_var = []

    for var in variables_of_eq:
        if var == " * " or var == "":
           pass
    else:
        variables_of_eq_ordered.append(var)
    for var in variables_of_eq_ordered:
        var = sym.Symbol(var)
        variables_of_eq_ord_var.append(var)

    print(sym.simplify(separatedeq))
    print(variables_of_eq_ordered)
    print(variables_of_eq_ord_var)

equationseparator("dy/dx=(6 * x) * (y) * (e**y)")
```

By using `variables_of_eq_ord_var` I get all the variables and append to the list. And I want to choose all the expressions that belong to y. But I couldn't make it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SymPy, why not use its solver for such equations?

```
>>> from sympy import S, Function
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> S('dydx-6*x*y*exp(y)').subs(y,f(x)).subs('dydx',f(x).diff(x))
-6*x*f(x)*exp(f(x)) + Derivative(f(x), x)
>>> dsolve(_)
Eq(Ei(exp_polar(I*pi)*f(x)), C1 + 3*x**2)
```

Else, if you have a product of factors and want those that contain a certain symbol you can just use `as_independent` to separate them:

```
>>> nony, withy = (x*y*exp(y)).as_independent(y); (nony, withy)
(x, y*exp(y))
```